# Applying shadow on uibutton Makes the button text blury

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, uibezierpath

Here is my code to add a shadow on my uibutton which is created using a .XIB file

```
UIBezierPath *shadowPathEndbtn = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0,  self->_navigationView.frame.size.height - 70,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width , 2)];
    self->_EndButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

    self->_EndButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self->_EndButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 5.0f);
    self->_EndButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
    self->_EndButton.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    self->_EndButton.layer.shadowPath = shadowPathForEndbtn.CGPath;
```

I am able to set the shadow using this code but this code makes my button text look blury. I am unable to figure out the exact reason behind this. Any help is Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self->_EndButton.layer.masksToBounds = false            
self->_EndButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor
self->_EndButton.layer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale];
self->_EndButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
self->_EndButton.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
self->_EndButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0)
```

This will give shadow and also the test is not blurry

Comment: What was making the button text look blury?

Comment: shadow path, is making the text blurry because of the UIBezierPath

Answer (score 0):

Set button background color

```
self.EndButton.BackgroundColor=[UIColor WhiteColor];
```